# c# Active Directory via WMI

Tags: c#, active-directory, wmi

Does anyone has some example about accessing Active Directory, LDAP querying using WMI (System.Management namespace) and not System.DirectoryServices namespace.

Here on MSDN page it is described a little using CIM classes 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392320(v=VS.85).aspx
But I cant find some C# example realizing it.

For example, to access some Win32 class you have to initialize Scope object to use CIMV2 namespace

```
private ConnectionOptions connection;
private ManagementScope scope;
...
connection = new ConnectionOptions();
...
scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + computer + "\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
try
{
   scope.Connect();
}
```

And use ObjectQuery class for querying WMI data

```
ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Processor");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, objectQuery);
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
return queryObj["Name"].ToString();
}
```

How is it possible to access AD using the same scope?
Thanks :)